# How to store data from a file read in binary mode C++

Tags: c++, file, iostream, fstream

Hi i am trying to read a file , say for  example 'sample.txt', in binary mode-c++ and i need to store the file text (eg."nodeA nodeB") in a vector . 
eg:
"A A B E A B G"
if this is what is in the text file , i want to read it in binary form and then store it in some variable and then do some operations to it .
Any help would be appreciated.
So far i have got is :

```
int main () {
  streampos begin,end;
  ifstream myfile ("example.bin", ios::binary);
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.close();
  cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The text part in the file myfile can be got how ?

Answer (score 3):

The method you are after is `ifstream::read(char *,streamsize)`.
Having gotten the size of the file in bytes, you can read the data into a `vector<char>` of the correct size (after seeking back to the beginning of the file):

```
streamsize n=end-begin;
vector<char> data((size_t)n);

myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
myfile.read(&data[0],n);
```

The iterator type of `vector<char>` may not necessarily be a `char *` pointer, so instead we pass as the first argument to read a pointer to the first element of the vector. The elements of a `std::vector` are guaranteed to be laid out contiguously, and so we can be assured that writing to `&data[0]+k` is equivalent to `&data[k]`, for valid indices k.

Comment: this is not binary mode , i NEED it in binary mode

Comment: If the stream is opened in binary mode, which you have done, then you have a stream which bypasses any operating specific text conversions (e.g., translation of newline characters to a native representation.)

Separate from that, you have the choice of using formatted (e.g. `operator>>`) or unformatted (e.g. `read` and `seekg`) operations. If you are performing unformatted operations on a stream that has been opened in binary mode, then you are getting the raw character data.

Answer (score 1):

Your file `sample.txt`, or whatever, is a *text* file. I believe
you want to "read it in binary form" because you think that you have 
to do that in order to find out the size of the data, so that you can then 
allocate storage of that size, in some variable, to contain the data.

In that case, really all you want to do is read a text file into a
suitable variable, and you can do this very simply, without having
to discover the length of the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

...

std::istream_iterator<char> eos; // An end-of-stream iterator
// Open your file
std::ifstream in("sample.txt"); 
if (!in) { // It didn't open for some reason.
    // So handle the error somehow and get out of here. 
}
// Your file opened OK
std::noskipws(in);  // You don't want to ignore whitespace when reading it
std::istream_iterator<char> in_iter(in); // An input-stream iterator for `in` 
std::string data;   // A string to store the data
std::copy(in_iter,eos,std::back_inserter(data)); // Copy the file to string
```

Now, the whole contents of `sample.txt` are in the string `data` and you
can parse it anyway you want. You could replace `std::string` with some
other standard container type of `char`, e.g. `std::vector<char>`, and
this would work just the same.